# Qt - Undefined Reference to Function - Dante API Library

Tags: c++, qt

I'm quite new to Qt and there seem to be some questions here that almost match my problem. However, I couldn't really find a working answer for me yet...

Here's my question:

I would like to use Qt and the Dante API library for implementing some Audio over IP functionalities. If I use Dante API functions within Qt the functions seem to get recognised by Qt, i.e. Qt gives me some information about the functions, e.g. about the return values of a function, if I click on the function's code. But, the project doesn't build and I get the following error messages:

*undefined reference to...* Dante API function name: e.g. aud_env_setup ... src  name: e.g. main.cpp
error: Id returned 1 exit status File not found:collect2.exe

According to audinate only the *dante.h file* needs to be included.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Here's my rather short code snippet for a console application:

main file:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <dante_api.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    aud_error_t result = AUD_SUCCESS;
    aud_env_t *my_env = NULL;

    result = aud_env_setup(&my_env);

    // Browsing
    db_browse_t * browse = NULL;
    db_browse_new(my_env, DB_BROWSE_TYPE_MEDIA_DEVICE, &browse);

    // Environment
    aud_env_release(my_env);

    return a.exec();
}
```

.pro file:

```
QT += core
QT += network
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = Dante_API_Console_Template_2
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += create_prl
CONFIG += link_prl

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += \
    DanteAPI/include/audinate

HEADERS += \
    DanteAPI/include/audinate/dante_api.h

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += \
    -L"C:/Users/chd/Documents/Qt_Software/Dante_API_Console_Template_2/DanteAPI/lib/Release/Win32" -ldante_dnssd \
```

Comment: If according to Audinate, only the header is needed, why are you including a library?

Comment: If you are using a binary library, make sure it was built with same compiler (brand, version, 32/64-bittiness) as your Qt project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need include Dante library headers into project! Remove this line of code from  `pro` file:

```
HEADERS += \
    DanteAPI/include/audinate/dante_api.h
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already tried this and other include-versions, but it didn't help. Im getting support by audinate at the moment (Thumps up! Brilliant support!). It could be that my Dante API file is corrupted. So I am trying to reinstall the Dante API now.

Answer (score 0):

In your Qt `.pro` file there is no `dapi.lib`

```
LIBS += \
-L"C:/Users/chd/Documents/Qt_Software/Dante_API_Console_Template_2/DanteAPI/lib/Release/Win32" -ldante_dnssd \
```

Presence of a trailing `\` on the end of that line. Do you have any lines underneath? If not, then you might have issues afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My apologies, you're absolutely right there is a line of code missing! I overlooked that I missed to copy in the line for the dapi.lib. The line was there, but it didn't help either. I had similar issues with compiling the short Dante API code snippet in Visual Studio Express 2013 and I got some really helpful support by audinate, which fixed this issue in VS-Express: I had to install the Dante API again from scratch and add paths to the following libraries (Linker-->Input-->Additional Dependencies): dapid.lib, dante_dnssd.lib, iphlpapi.lib, ws2_32.lib ...

Comment: ... I am now trying to do the same in Qt (msvc-2013) and/or combine Qt and Visual Studio Express. But, I still haven't found a solution yet.